# Efficient modelling via Gurobi

Tags: modeling, constraint, gurobi, java

I would like to model the following constraint set in gurobi-java.

\begin{equation}
t^n_{ij} \geq t^n_{(i-1)j}+S_{(i-1)j} - (1 - \sum_{\substack{m \in \mathcal{M} \\ G_{ijm} = 1}}\sum_{k \in \mathcal{K}} x^n_{ijmk}) \times \Omega
    \hspace{1cm} \forall j \in \mathcal{J}; i \in \mathcal{I}_j/1; n \in \mathcal{N}_j
\end{equation}

where $t^n_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ and $x^n_{ijmk} \in \{0,1\}$ are decision variables. I have modeled this constraint set in gurobi-java as follows:

```
GRBVar[][][][][] x = new GRBVar[i_idx][j_idx][n_idx][m_idx][k_idx];
for (int j : j_set) {
    for (int i : i_set[j]) {
        for (int n : n_set[j]) {
            for (int m : m_set) {
                if (G[i][j][m] == true) {
                    for (int k : k_set) {
                        x[i][j][n][m][k] = model.addVar(0, 1, 1, GRB.BINARY,
                                i + "_" + j + "_" + n + "_" + m + "_" + k);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

GRBVar[][][] t = new GRBVar[i_idx][j_idx][n_idx];
for (int j : j_set) {
    for (int i : i_set[j]) {
        for (int n : n_set[j]) {
            t[i][j][n] = model.addVar(0, GRB.INFINITY, 0, GRB.CONTINUOUS,
                    i + "_" + j + "_" + n);
        }
    }
}

GRBVar[][][] auxvar1 = new GRBVar[i_idx][j_idx][n_idx];
for (int j : j_set) {
    for (int i : i_set[j]) {
        for (int n : n_set[j]) {
            auxvar1[i][j][n] = model.addVar(0, 1, 1, GRB.BINARY,
                    i + "_" + j + "_" + n);

            GRBLinExpr lhs = new GRBLinExpr();
            GRBLinExpr rhs = new GRBLinExpr();

            lhs.addTerm(1, auxvar1[i][j][n]);
            rhs.addConstant(1);
            for (int m : m_set) {
                if (G[i][j][m] == true) {
                    for (int k : k_set) {
                        rhs.addTerm(-1, x[i][j][n][m][k]);
                    }
                }
            }

            model.addConstr(lhs, GRB.EQUAL, rhs, "auxiliary_" + i + "_" + j + "_" + n);
        }
    }
}


for (int j : j_set) {
    for (int i = 1; i < i_set[j].length; i++) {
        for (int n : n_set[j]) {
            GRBLinExpr lhs = new GRBLinExpr();
            GRBLinExpr rhs = new GRBLinExpr();

            lhs.addTerm(1, t[i][j][n]);

            rhs.addTerm(1, t[i-1][j][n]);
            rhs.addConstant(S[j][i-1]);
            rhs.addTerm(-Omega, auxvar1[i][j][n]);

            model.addConstr(lhs, GRB.GREATER_EQUAL, rhs, "time_flow_" + i + "_" + j + "_" + n);
        }
    }
}
```

In comparison to docplex-python, it is much less readable and requires much more lines of code.

```
mdl.add_constraints(t[i, j ,n] >= t[i-1, j, n] + S[i-1, j] - (1 - mdl.sum(x[i, j, n, m, k] for m in m_set if G[i, j, m] == 1 for k in k_set) * Omega for j in j_set for i in i_set[j] if i > 0 for n in n_set[j]))
```

I am new to gurobi-java. Are there any better ways to model this constraint set.

Comment: Gurobi also has [`Model.addVars`](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_addvars.html) and [`Model.addConstrs`](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_addconstrs.html) that are used to create variables and constraints in a batch

Comment: Those you pointed out are for Python. Similar functions are available for Java, however, I think they do not allow for the inline construction of variables and constraints. For example, one should determine arrays of `lhsExprs`, `senses`, `rhss` and `names` (you need the multiple loops in multiple lines).

Comment: Java links: [GRBModel.addVars()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/java_model_addvars.html), [GRBModel.addConstrs()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/java_model_addconstrs.html). Full list of [Java Examples](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/examples/java_examples.html), particularly, no example uses `addConstrs` as Java doesn't have nice list-comprehensions like Python. A few use `addVars`: e.g. [GCPWL.java](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/examples/gcpwl_java.html).

Comment: Without the intention of triggering a language war now, I believe it's worth mentioning that Java doesn't support operator overloading, so the readability of math-related java code is limited by nature.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the answer you want, but Gurobi has a very nice Python interface. I'd be surprised if there was anything you liked from `docplex` that you wouldn't find to be at least as good or better in `gurobipy`.

When porting Python code to Java code, as a rule, there will probably a loss in readability/brevity. That's why Python is far more popular for data science, and now, for even general purpose programming.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).